# Aluminium foil not blocking IR signal

Tags: infrared, physics, electrical, materials, conductive

I am using an IR sensor (vishay tsop32 series) but I want to ensure that it only sender directly ahead so I made blinders out of pla and covered them in aluminium foil. However it seems that despite this the IR signal is able to be detected through the foil. Even when I surround the sensor with aluminium foil it is sensing an IR signal. The aluminium foil has decreased the sensing distance but not as much as is necessary. I'm wondering why this is not working as well as expected and what materials might work better as blinders for the sensor.

Comment: Wouldn't a material which absorbs IR work better instead of one that is highly reflective?

Comment: Yes! I Agree with @Arsenal. I think your IR signal is getting reflected from the Aluminium foil and somehow getting re-reflected off some other material and reaching it to your detector. So, it is best to use some opaque and non-reflective material for the blinder (i.e black plastic material or cardboard would work just fine).

Comment: @dr3patel note that black plastic might still be too reflective (most of the plastics come out of a polished form), so it might be needed to roughen up the surface to get better absorption.

Comment: @Arsenal yes, agreed!

Comment: Post a photo of your problem layout.

Comment: Be careful. Many types of plastic (e.g. polyethylene) are very transparent to IR. For example, a black plastic garbage bag is almost invisible -- you can easily find videos on YouTube demonstrating this.

Comment: I don't believe IR is passing through aluminium foil. There must be a gap within the foil cover.

Comment: Paint your blinders with flat black paint.

Comment: you are not thinking clearly .... you are using a mirror to prevent reflections

Comment: Ah ok yeah it's possible it's getting reflected off the foil and getting back to the sensor. I was thinking once it gets reflected it probably would be much weaker if it did reflect back but I guess it could.

Comment: Also plastic is an issue. As someone said pla is almost entirely transparent to the IR. Maybe other plastics might work better but I will probably use wood and paint it black. Thank you!

Comment: Try a Blue plastic straw, or cluster of them if your pickup device is large.

Comment: Use a black tube, with soot (from a candle flame) deposited inside the tube.